# Understanding c# syntax of return statement

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to understand the syntax of a piece of code someone else wrote.

The method is returning a bool, and the return statement looks like this:

```
 return user.UserStatus == Models.User.UserStatuses.Inactive && user.IsLocked;
```

UserStatuses is a enum.

So it appears to me it returns the property of object user called UserStatus, however UserStatus is an enum, not a bool, and then && adds the bool as user.IsLocked, where is a bool.

I can't seem to understand how this is legal in c#, since it appears to return two parameters.

Comment: return a == b && c makes more sense?

Comment: it doesn't return two parameters, it is checking that user.UserStatus equals the Inactive status and the bool value user.IsLocked is truthy (true). if both are true, it returns true. otherwise, false

Comment: `user.UserStatus == Models.User.UserStatuses.Inactive` is a boolean. UserStatus is either Inactive or not.  user.IsLocked is also a boolean. Now you have `boolean` && `boolean`, which should make sense.

Comment: So I can return any  number of bools and the result will automatically be combined into one bool?

Comment: @Dylan If you combine them with statements like && and || yes, because in the end the *expression* still returns a single bool

Answer (score 4):

Add some parenthesis, or separate your line into multiple statements, and it makes sense. The compiler is just doing it for you (more or less). Your statement is equivalent to:

```
return ((user.UserStatus == Models.User.UserStatuses.Inactive) && user.IsLocked);
```

or

```
bool inactive = user.UserStatus == Models.User.UserStatuses.Inactive;
bool inactiveAndLocked = inactive && user.isLocked;
return inactiveAndLocked;
```

The key here is that return is taking an *expression* (not a parameter) and using the result of that expression, which is just one "thing" as the C# spec dictates.

Comment: The actual "bool" being returned is actually an enum, that's what's throwing me off.  It's defined an as int in SQL, not a bool, yet it gets returns as a bool?

Comment: @Dylan Could you be more specific? No enum is returned since the expression `<object> == <object>` always returns a `bool` (definition of `==` operator)

Comment: I understand the idea, I think it's just the syntax that's throwing me way off here.  When you write it as an if statement it makes allot more sense.

Comment: @Dylan Try to remember that an `if` statement is *also* utilizing a Boolean expression (just like here). There is *no difference* between using it in a return (that returns a bool) and using it in an `if`

Answer (score 0):

It is just returning a boolean condition. Hypothetically, you could also check that same code on a IF statement like:

```
if(user.UserStatus == Models.User.UserStatuses.Inactive && user.IsLocked)
```

Comment: No problem, just thought it was a word I wasn't familiar with on first read, then realized it was probably a misspelling and wanted to make sure :)

Answer (score 0):

```
bool result = (user.UserStatus == Models.User.UserStatuses.Inactive) &&
               user.IsLocked;
return result;
```

Comment: While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.

Answer (score -1):

UserStatus is an enum but the base type of an enum is int.  This is compared to the specific enum type.  So the first part is basically (int == int) which yields a bool.  The bool is then conditionally and'ed with the IsLocked value (bool && bool) to yield the final result.